# Class attribute not set! at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, classification, weka

I have this code

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.supervised.instance.Resample;

import java.util.Random;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader ;

import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal;
public class LoadModelWeka
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   // training
      BufferedReader reader = null;
      reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\Licenta\\partXML\\TestTask1_partXML.arff"));
      Instances train =new Instances (reader);
      Instances classBalancerInstances=homogenizeTrainingData(train);
     // classBalancerInstances.setClassIndex(classBalancerInstances.numAttributes() - 1);
      classBalancerInstances.setClassIndex(0);     
      reader.close();

      NaiveBayes nb = new NaiveBayes();
      nb.buildClassifier(classBalancerInstances);
      Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(classBalancerInstances);
      eval.crossValidateModel(nb, classBalancerInstances, 10 , new Random(1));

      System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\n Results \n=====\n",true));
      System.out.println(eval.fMeasure(1)+" "+eval.precision(1)+" "+eval.recall(1)+" ");           
   }   

   public static Instances homogenizeTrainingData(Instances data) throws Exception
   {
    final Resample filter = new Resample();
    Instances filteredIns = null;
    filter.setBiasToUniformClass(1.0);
    Instances newData=convertToNominal(data);
    try {
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
        filter.setInputFormat(newData);
        filter.setNoReplacement(false);
        filter.setSampleSizePercent(100);
        filteredIns = Filter.useFilter(newData, filter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error when resampling input data!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return filteredIns;

   }


public static Instances convertToNominal(Instances originalTrain) throws Exception{

    NumericToNominal convert= new NumericToNominal();
    String[] options= new String[2];
    options[0]="-R";
    options[1]="1-9";  //range of variables to make numeric

    convert.setOptions(options);
    convert.setInputFormat(originalTrain);

    Instances newData=Filter.useFilter(originalTrain, convert);

    System.out.println("Before");
    for(int i=0; i<2; i=i+1)
    {
        System.out.println("Nominal? "+originalTrain.attribute(i).isNominal());
    }

    System.out.println("After");
    for(int i=0; i<2; i=i+1)
    {
        System.out.println("Nominal? "+newData.attribute(i).isNominal());
    }
    return newData;

}
}
```

Here I want to filter my dataset with class balancer but an error appeared and said that the attributes must be nominal.I have tried to convert to nominal but this error occured:

```
weka.core.UnassignedClassException: weka.filters.supervised.instance.Resample: Class attribute not set!
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Unknown Source)
    at weka.filters.Filter.testInputFormat(Unknown Source)
    at weka.filters.Filter.setInputFormat(Unknown Source)
    at weka.filters.supervised.instance.Resample.setInputFormat(Unknown Source)
    at licenta1.LoadModelWeka.homogenizeTrainingData(LoadModelWeka.java:44)
    at licenta1.LoadModelWeka.main(LoadModelWeka.java:22)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at licenta1.LoadModelWeka.main(LoadModelWeka.java:24)
```

I have tried to resolve it to set the class index but I don't understand very well how it works so I don't know how to set the instances to work well.
My file is an arff with 9 attributes and the classification is made with attribute number 9 so I think , I must convert all columns for 1 to 9, but I am not sure if I understood good hoe the filter and the conversion from Numeric to Nominal works.

Can help me somebody?

My .arff file looks like the code bellow:

```
@attribute Word {Induction,of,during,monocyte,differentiation,by,HIV,type,1.0,infection,Electrophoretic,mobility,experiments,were,usedare,the,mostmayat,me,to,detect,located,in,long,terminal,repeat,PMA,treatment,acts,probablyin,inducing,expression,nuclei,In,nuclear,extracts,from,monocytes,or,macrophages,induction,occurred,only,if,cells,previously,infected,with,When,U937,no,factor,was,detected,whereas,high,level,progeny,virions,produced,suggesting,that,this,not,required,These,results,indicate,monocytic,cell,lineage,could,mimic,some,stimuli,allowing,Positive,and,negative,regulation,immunoglobulinis,most,suggesthere,gene,a,novel,enhancer,element,A,new,specific,Tandem,copies,fragment,transcription,B,but,Jurkat,T,HeLa,Footprinting,analysis,revealed,Hex,Gel,addition,ubiquitous,band,found,also,agreement,gel,may,Furthermorein,vivo,activity,striking,contrast,mouse,sequence,very,its,own,Interestingly,suppress,promoter,Moreover,simian,virus,40.0,blocked,Thus,identified,study,is,probably,target,site,for,both,positive,factors,The,production,human,immunodeficiency,purified}
@attribute w-2 {'null  ','Induction  ','of  ','during  ','monocyte  ','differentiation  ','by  ','HIV  ','type  ',1.0,'infection  ','Electrophoretic  ','mobility  ','experiments  ','were  ','usedare  ','the  ','mostmayat  ','me  ','to  ','detect  ','located  ','in  ','long  ','terminal  ','repeat  ','PMA  ','treatment  ','acts  ','probablyin  ','inducing  ','expression  ','nuclei  ','In  ','nuclear  ','extracts  ','from ','monocytes  ','or  ','macrophages  ','induction  ','occurred  ','only  ','if  ','cells  ','previously  ','infected  ','with  ','When  ','U937  ','no  ','factor  ','was  ','detected  ','whereas  ','high  ','level  ','progeny  ','virions  ','was ','produced  ','suggesting  ','that  ','this  ','not  ','required  ','These  ','results  ','indicate  ','monocytic  ','cell ','lineage  ','could  ','mimic  ','some  ','stimuli  ','allowing  ','Positive  ','and  ','negative  ','regulation  ','immunoglobulinis  ','most  ','suggesthere  ','gene  ','a  ','novel  ','enhancer  ','element  ','A  ','new  ','specific  ','Tandem  ','copies  ','fragment  ','transcription  ','B  ','but  ','Jurkat  ','T ','HeLa  ','Footprinting  ','analysis  ','revealed  ','from  ','Hex  ','Gel  ','addition  ','ubiquitous  ','band  ','found  ','also  ','T  ','agreement  ','gel  ','in ','may  ','Furthermorein  ','vivo  ','activity  ','striking  ','contrast  ','mouse  ','sequence  ','very  ','its  ','own  ','Interestingly  ','the ','suppress  ','promoter  ','Moreover  ','simian  ','virus  ',40.0,'blocked  ','Thus  ','identified  ','study ','is  ','probably  ','target  ','site  ','for  ','both  ','positive  ','factors  ','The  ','production  ','human  ','immunodeficiency  ','purified  ','human ','monocytes '}
@attribute w-1 {' null  ',' Induction ',' of ',' during ',' monocyte ',' differentiation ',' by ',' HIV ',' type ',1.0,' infection ',' Electrophoretic ',' mobility ',' experiments ',' were ',' usedare ',' the ',' mostmayat ',' me ',' to ',' detect ',' located ',' in ',' long ',' terminal ',' repeat ',' PMA ',' treatment ',' acts ',' probablyin ',' inducing ',' expression ',' nuclei ',' In ',' nuclear ',' extracts ',' from ','  monocytes ',' or ',' macrophages ',' induction ',' occurred ',' only ',' if ',' cells ',' previously ',' infected ',' with ',' When ',' U937 ',' no ',' factor ',' was ',' detected ',' whereas ',' high ',' level ',' progeny ',' virions ','  produced ',' suggesting ',' that ',' this ',' not ',' required ',' These ',' results ',' indicate ',' monocytic ',' cell ','  lineage ',' could ',' mimic ',' some ',' stimuli ',' allowing ',' Positive ',' and ',' negative ',' regulation ',' immunoglobulinis ',' most ',' suggesthere ',' gene ',' a ',' novel ',' enhancer ',' element ',' A ',' new ',' specific ',' Tandem ',' copies ',' fragment ',' transcription ',' B ',' but ',' Jurkat ',' T ','  cells ',' HeLa ',' Footprinting ',' analysis ',' revealed ',' Hex ',' Gel ',' addition ',' ubiquitous ',' band ',' found ',' also ',' agreement ',' gel ','  Jurkat ',' may ',' Furthermorein ',' vivo ',' activity ',' striking ',' contrast ',' mouse ',' sequence ',' very ',' its ',' own ',' Interestingly ','  fragment ',' suppress ',' promoter ',' Moreover ',' simian ',' virus ',40.0,' blocked ',' Thus ',' identified ',' study ','  is ',' probably ',' target ',' site ',' for ',' both ',' positive ',' factors ',' The ',' production ',' human ',' immunodeficiency ',' purified ','  and '}
@attribute w {' Induction ','  of ','  during ','  monocyte ','  differentiation ','  by ','  HIV ','  type ',1.0,'  infection ','  Electrophoretic ','  mobility ','  experiments ','  were ','  usedare ','  the ','  mostmayat ','  me ','  to ','  detect ','  located ','  in ','  long ','  terminal ','  repeat ','  PMA ','  treatment ','  acts ','  probablyin ','  inducing ','  expression ','  nuclei ','  In ','  nuclear ','  extracts ','  from ','  monocytes ','  or  ','  macrophages ','  induction ','  occurred ','  only ','  if ','  cells ','  previously ','  infected ','  with ','  When ','  U937 ','  no ','  factor ','  was ','  detected ','  whereas ','  high ','  level ','  progeny ','  virions ','  produced ','  suggesting  ','  that ','  this ','  not ','  required ','  These ','  results ','  indicate ','  monocytic ','  cell ','  lineage ','  could  ','  mimic ','  some ','  stimuli ','  allowing ','  Positive ','  and ','  negative ','  regulation ','  immunoglobulinis ','  most ','  suggesthere ','  gene ','  a ','  novel ','  enhancer ','  element ','  A ','  new ','  specific ','  Tandem ','  copies ','  fragment ','  transcription ','  B ','  but ','  Jurkat ','  T ','  HeLa ','  Footprinting ','  analysis ','  revealed ','  Hex ','  Gel ','  addition ','  ubiquitous ','  band ','  found ','  also ','  agreement ','  gel ','  may  ','  Furthermorein ','  vivo ','  activity ','  striking ','  contrast ','  mouse ','  sequence ','  very ','  its ','  own ','  Interestingly ','  suppress ','  promoter ','  Moreover ','  simian ','  virus ',40.0,'  blocked ','  Thus ','  identified ','  study ','  is ','  probably  ','  target ','  site ','  for ','  both ','  positive ','  factors ','  The ','  production ','  human ','  immunodeficiency ','  purified ','  macrophages  '}
@attribute w+1 {'  of ','  during  ','  monocyte  ','  differentiation  ','  by  ','  HIV  ','  type  ',1.0,'  infection  ','  Electrophoretic  ','  mobility  ','  experiments  ','  were  ','  usedare  ','  the  ','  mostmayat  ','  me  ','  to  ','  detect  ','  located  ','  in  ','  long  ','  terminal  ','  repeat  ','  PMA  ','  treatment  ','  acts  ','  probablyin  ','  inducing  ','  expression  ','  nuclei  ','  In  ','  nuclear  ','  extracts  ','  from  ','  monocytes  ','  or  ',' macrophages ','  induction  ','  of  ','  occurred  ','  only  ','  if  ','  cells  ','  previously  ','  infected  ','  with  ','  When  ','  U937  ','  no  ','  factor  ','  was  ','  detected  ','  whereas  ','  high  ','  level  ','  progeny  ','  virions  ','  produced  ','  suggesting  ',' that ','  this  ','  not  ','  required  ','  These  ','  results  ','  indicate  ','  that  ','  monocytic  ','  cell  ','  lineage  ','  could  ',' mimic ','  some  ','  stimuli  ','  allowing  ','  Positive  ','  and  ','  negative  ','  regulation  ','  immunoglobulinis  ','  most  ','  suggesthere  ','  gene  ','  a  ','  novel  ','  enhancer  ','  element  ','  A  ','  new  ','  specific  ','  Tandem  ','  copies  ','  fragment  ','  transcription  ','  B  ','  but  ','  Jurkat  ','  T  ',' HeLa ','  Footprinting  ','  analysis  ','  revealed  ',' Hex ','  Gel  ','  addition  ','  ubiquitous  ','  band  ','  found  ','  also  ','  HeLa  ','  agreement  ','  gel  ','  may  ','  Furthermorein  ','  vivo  ','  activity  ','  striking  ','  contrast  ','  mouse  ','  sequence  ','  very  ','  its  ','  own  ','  Interestingly  ',' suppress ','  promoter  ','  Moreover  ','  simian  ','  virus  ',40.0,'  blocked  ','  Thus  ','  identified  ','  study  ','  is  ','  probably  ',' a ','  target  ','  site  ','  for  ','  both  ','  positive  ','  factors  ','  The  ','  production  ','  human  ','  immunodeficiency  ','  purified  ','  macrophages  ',' null '}
@attribute w+2 {'  during  ',' monocyte ',' differentiation ',' by ',' HIV ',' type ',1.0,' infection ',' Electrophoretic ',' mobility ',' experiments ',' were ',' usedare ',' the ',' mostmayat ',' me ',' to ',' detect ',' located ',' in ',' long ',' terminal ',' repeat ',' PMA ',' treatment ',' acts ',' probablyin ',' inducing ',' expression ',' nuclei ',' In ',' nuclear ',' extracts ',' from ',' monocytes ',' or ',' macrophages ','  induction ',' of ',' occurred ',' only ',' if ',' cells ',' previously ',' infected ',' with ',' When ',' U937 ',' no ',' induction ',' factor ',' was ',' detected ',' whereas ',' high ',' level ',' progeny ',' virions ',' produced ',' suggesting ',' that ','  this ',' not ',' required ',' These ',' results ',' indicate ',' monocytic ',' cell ',' lineage ',' could ',' mimic ','  some ',' stimuli ',' allowing ',' Positive ',' and ',' negative ',' regulation ',' immunoglobulinis ',' most ',' suggesthere ',' gene ',' a ',' novel ',' enhancer ',' element ',' A ',' new ',' specific ',' Tandem ',' copies ',' this ',' fragment ',' transcription ',' B ',' but ',' Jurkat ',' T ',' HeLa ','  cells ',' Footprinting ',' analysis ',' revealed ',' Hex ',' Gel ',' addition ',' ubiquitous ',' band ',' found ',' also ',' agreement ',' gel ',' may ',' Furthermorein ',' vivo ',' activity ',' striking ',' contrast ',' mouse ',' sequence ',' very ',' its ',' own ',' Interestingly ',' suppress ','  promoter ',' Moreover ',' simian ',' virus ',40.0,' blocked ',' Thus ',' identified ',' study ',' is ',' probably ','  target ',' site ',' for ',' both ',' positive ',' factors ',' The ',' production ',' human ',' immunodeficiency ',' purified ',' null ','  null '}
@attribute Lemma {induction,of,during,monocyte,differentiation,by,hiv,type,1.0,infection,electrophoretic,mobility,experiment,be,usedare,the,mostmayat,I,to,detect,located,in,long,terminal,repeat,pma,treatment,act,probablyin,induce,expression,nucleus,nuclear,extract,from,or,macrophage,occur,only,if,cell,previously,infected,with,when,u937,no,factor,whereas,high,level,progeny,virion,produce,suggest,that,this,not,require,these,result,indicate,monocytic,lineage,could,mimic,some,stimulus,allow,positive,and,negative,regulation,immunoglobulinis,most,suggesthere,gene,a,novel,enhancer,element,new,specific,Tandem,copy,fragment,transcription,b,but,jurkat,t,hela,footprinting,analysis,reveal,hex,gel,addition,ubiquitous,band,find,also,agreement,may,furthermorein,vivo,activity,striking,contrast,mouse,sequence,very,its,own,interestingly,suppress,promoter,moreover,simian,virus,40.0,block,thus,identify,study,probably,target,site,for,both,production,human,immunodeficiency,purify}
@attribute POS {NNP,IN,NN,CD,RB,NNS,VBD,DT,PRP,TO,VB,VBN,UH,WRB,JJ,VBG,MD,JJS,SYM,VBZ}
@attribute IsCue {'  F','  T'}

@data
Induction,'null  ',' null  ',' Induction ','  of ','  during  ',induction,NNP,'  F'
of,'null  ',' Induction ','  of ','  during  ',' monocyte ',of,IN,'  F'
during,'Induction  ',' of ','  during ','  monocyte  ',' differentiation ',during,IN,'  F'
monocyte,'of  ',' during ','  monocyte ','  differentiation  ',' by ',monocyte,NN,'  F'
differentiation,'during  ',' monocyte ','  differentiation ','  by  ',' HIV ',differentiation,NN,'  F'
by,'monocyte  ',' differentiation ','  by ','  HIV  ',' type ',by,IN,'  F'
HIV,'differentiation  ',' by ','  HIV ','  type  ',1.0,hiv,NNP,'  F'
type,'by  ',' HIV ','  type ',1.0,' infection ',type,NN,'  F'
1.0,'HIV  ',' type ',1.0,'  infection  ',' Electrophoretic ',1.0,CD,'  F'
infection,'type  ',1.0,'  infection ','  Electrophoretic  ',' mobility ',infection,NN,'  F'
```

The classification must be in function of IsCue attribute.IsCue is true if the current word(I mean the first word on the line)  is certain and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this question and I posted it.Ithink can help somebody.
ClassIndex is the index of class that I want to use in the classification precess.In my example I wanted to classfiy by useing the attribute IsCue, so I need to add the next line inthe method numericTonNominal.It must be the first line in my method like this:

```
    public static Instances convertToNominal(Instances originalTrain) throws Exception{
            originalTrain.setClassIndex(8);
//your code here
}
```

I set the index to 8 because my attribute is number 9, but it starts to 0, so it will become number 8 in the classification process